# Extract (schema) tags from xml

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have an xml file, where the schema information are included. To validate the xml, I want to extract the schema information. How can I achieve this either by phyton script or xslt transformation? The validation will take place in the nifi xmlValidator processor.

I tried a xsl Transformation but the xsd prefix is the problem.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata">
    <xsd:schema>
    <xsd:element name="dataroot">
    <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xsd:element ref="AE"></xsd:element> 
   ...
    </xsd:schema> 
    <dataroot>
   ...</dataroot>
   </root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the XSD part from your with the following XSLT-1.0 stylesheet. First, it matches the `/root` element and then copies all of the `xsd:...` children with a custom *identity template*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- Identity template for 'xsd' -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="xsd">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="xsd" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="/root/xsd:schema">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="xsd" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>         

    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="dataroot">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded"><xsd:element ref="AE"/>

                    ...
                </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I ignored the `...`, because they are probably not part of the XML.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this correctly, but to get the `dataroot` part, remove the both `mode="xsd"` from the identity template and then replace the other template with `<xsl:template match="/root/xsd:schema" />`.

Comment: I tried your version, but in the last line of the transformed xml, there are the values of the deleted tags inside the dataroot tag. Is it possible to remove these values?

Comment: ok, add the template `<xsl:template match="text()" />` to get rid of superfluos text nodes.

Comment: I need one more modification, the child element of xsd:schema named "od:index" should be excepted from copiing, is this possible?

Comment: Add the namespace `xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata"` to the stylesheet element and then add an empty template like this: `<xsl:template match="od:index" mode="xsd" />` to remove the "od:index" element or `<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri() = 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata']" mode="xsd" />` to remove all "od:..." elements.

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT 2.0 stylesheet splits the document into a schema document and an instance document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0"> 

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="xsd:schema">
        <xsl:result-document href="schema.xsd">
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: is there a way to keep only the schema?

Comment: Yes of course, but you're asking very basic stuff here: what have you read, what have you tried, where did you hit difficulties?

Comment: I want to use the extracted schema to validate it against the xml data, does this make sense?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, what I don't know is what part of the process you are having difficulty with.

Comment: I tried your version without the first template, only the match="xsd:schema" part, without a reference to a result-document, now I have the problem, that the values of the removed tags are still at the end of the document, is it possible to remove these?

Comment: If you only want to extract the schema, just do `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:copy-of select="/*/xsd:schema"/></xsl:template>`